# How to send video (Larg size) inside post request?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my case I want to send video to my host through post request.

I finish of many steps:

1- I can get a video file from the gallery with `File` Data Type. (Using image_picker).

```
videoSelectorGallery() async {
      VideoFile = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
      );

      _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(VideoFile)..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() { });
      });

      print("You selected gallery video : " + VideoFile.path);

        .
        .
        .

    }
```

2- I change it to String64bytes.

```
        .
        .
        .

      // Convert from file to String64byte
      videoBytes = await VideoFile.readAsBytesSync();
      base64Video = base64Encode(videoBytes);
      print(base64Video);


    }
```

3- I send String64bytes with post request.

```
        .
        .
        .
var body = json.encode(
        {
          "shopName":...,
          "description":...,
          "typeID":...,
          "video": base64Video // <---- String64bytes
        }
    );
        .
        .
        .
```

**The problem** : When I send this request, it gets very long time to finish and the reason because the video has large size.

**I think** the best way to send faster is to compress the video but I don't know how and I search before about compressing videos useing flutter, I found some ways but still not work for me.

Any one know beeter idea how to send faster or good way to compress ?

Comment: Why are you sending data in base64 anyway? Can't you use Multipart?

Comment: Guys who work on back-end, they builded the web service to get videos as String64Bytes

Comment: are they aware that it will enlarge the data sent over the wire by 133%? so if your video has 1GB you would need to sent 1.33GB?

Comment: Really !!   What is the best way to send video?

Comment: see [MultipartFile](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile-class.html)